# How to save a php variable value to javascript variable using $.get()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like this:

```
jQuery.fn.stickyNotes.createNote = function(root) {

   var record_no;

   $.get(root+"/blocks/stickynotes/max_records.php", function(resp) {
      alert(resp);
      record_no=resp;
   })

   var note_stickyid = record_no;
   ...
}
```

The max_record.php looks like this:

```
 <?php
     require_once('../../config.php');
     global $DB;

     $max_id = $DB->get_record_sql('
                  SELECT max(stickyid) as max_id   
                  FROM mdl_block_stickynotes
               ');
     $stickyid= $max_id->max_id+1;
     echo $stickyid;
 ?>
```

I wondering why records_no has no value in it, while resp is showing right value in alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
var note_stickyid = record_no;
```

The `$.get()` function above it is asynchronous, so it's trying to assign this value before the function has completed. Assign the variable inside the callback:

```
var note_stickyid;

$.get(root+"/blocks/stickynotes/max_records.php", function(resp) {
  alert(resp);
  record_no=resp;
  note_stickyid = record_no;
}).done(function() {
  alert(note_stickyid); //Works because it waits until the request is done
});

alert(note_stickyid); //This will alert null, because it triggers before the function has assigned!
```

In your case, you'll probably want to pass in a callback function so you can actually use this variable, here's a sample callback function:

```
function callback(param) {
    alert(param);
}
```

Now setup another parameter for your `createNote`:

```
jQuery.fn.stickyNotes.createNote = function(root, callback) {
```

Now use that callback inside the `$.get`:

```
var note_stickyid;

$.get(root+"/blocks/stickynotes/max_records.php", function(resp) {
  alert(resp);
  record_no=resp;
  note_stickyid = record_no;
  callback(note_stickyid);
});
```

Comment: How is it different than what I am doing now. You are declaring a variable outside the callback function and updating it inside the it,which I am doing using the record_no. Your solution throws the same problem. It returns null value.

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK - You're assigning `record_no` inside the function then trying to use it outside the function right away, it won't be assigned!

Comment: I am still getting undefined error for note_stickyid variable.

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK -- Pass in a callback function, I'll edit my answer, give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: would you please elaborate how the callback works here, that you're creating? As far as I understand is the callback ensures the note_stickyid to have some value right?

Comment: Yes, the callback is called with `note_sticky` as a parameter, that way you can do whatever you want with it inside that callback function. So, you would call the stickyNote function like `stickyNote("rootValue", callback)`. Don't put `()` after the function when using it as a parameter, or else it will invoke it immediately, and we don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var record_no= '';

   $.get(root+"/blocks/stickynotes/max_records.php", function(resp) {
      alert(resp);
      record_no+=resp;
   })
```